# Using a .bat to extract text between two words

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a media server and I'm attempting to automate ripping my collection of movies and any future movies using MakeMKV. Ripping and moving is working without a hitch. The problem I'm running into is occasionally MakeMKV doesn't assign a title to the MKVs and I end up with `title00.mkv` which Media Center Master obviously cannot even begin to try to match to any metadata.

MakeMKV does offer the ability to get the information from the disc which I have print to `info.txt` which looks like this.

```
MSG:1005,0,1,"MakeMKV v1.8.10 win(x64-release) started","%1 started","MakeMKV v1.8.10 win(x64-release)"
DRV:0,2,999,1,"HD-DVD-ROM HL-DT-ST BD-RE  GGW-H20L YL05","FARFROMHOME_16X9","\\Device\\CdRom0"
DRV:1,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:2,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:3,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:4,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:5,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:6,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:7,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:8,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:9,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:10,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:11,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:12,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:13,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:14,256,999,0,"","",""
DRV:15,256,999,0,"","",""
```

`FARFROMHOME_16X9` is the label for the disc.

How can I extract this and rename my .mkv when `makemkv` has finished?

Here is my BAT so far (my first attempt at a .bat):

```
makemkvcon64 -r info disc > info.txt
makemkvcon64 --minlength=3600 mkv disc:0 all C:\Users\HTPC\MakeMKV_Temp\
START /WAIT makemkvcon64.exe
cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\FreeEject\"
FreeEject d:
move C:\Users\HTPC\MakeMKV_Temp\*.mkv C:\Users\HTPC\Movies\
```

Renaming the file before the move would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you posted an ample description of your problem and data, you have not *explained* what exactly you want as result, so I must guess a couple points. The lines below extract *the sixth comma-separated token from the second line* of info.txt file:

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=6 delims=," %%a in (info.txt) do set "discLabel=%%~a" & goto continue
:continue
echo The label of the disk is: %discLabel%
```

This is the output of previous lines when they are executed on your example data:

```
The label of the disk is: FARFROMHOME_16X9
```

You also have *not* indicated the name of the file you want to rename (before move it). Below is a possible solution to your problem that should be adjusted when previous unclear points be defined:

```
makemkvcon64 -r info disc > info.txt
for /F "skip=1 tokens=6 delims=," %%a in (info.txt) do set "discLabel=%%~a" & goto continue
:continue
makemkvcon64 --minlength=3600 mkv disc:0 all C:\Users\HTPC1\MakeMKV_Temp\
START /WAIT makemkvcon64.exe
cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\FreeEject\"
FreeEject d:
ren C:\Users\HTPC1\MakeMKV_Temp\TheNameHere.mkv %discLabel%.mkv
move C:\Users\HTPC1\MakeMKV_Temp\*.mkv C:\Users\HTPC1\Movies\
```

Comment: Thanks Aacini! Sorry, I wasn't clear on those points. Great assumptions none-the-less. MakeMKV generates it's own filename. Sometimes it's the disc title, but often it's some form of title##.mkv. Considering there should only be one .mkv in the temp directory after MakeMKV is complete, I assume it should be safe to replace TheNameHere.mkv with *.mkv.

Comment: Yes, as long as there is just _one_ file with .mkv extension

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrangling with the same thing and created something that works fairly well.

MakeMKV uses it's own output FileName like you indicated "title00.mkv" or something similar.

I've created two(2) batch files to perform my home movie automation.
The first is "RipWorkflow_DVD.bat", which handles all the heavy lifting to call MakeMKV first to rip the content to my drive. Also in this file is a call to Handbrake to convert the MKV to MP4 (my stupid "smart" tv won't play MKV, but likes MP4)

The second batch file "OneStepDVDRip.bat" calls the first, but with parameters I choose for 
a) location of the MKV
b) the output name of my MP4
c) the minLength of a track to locate and rip to MKV

Here is the code for "OneStepDVDRip.bat"

```
    call "C:\Users\Todd\Desktop\RipWorkflow_DVD.bat" "Z:\Video\TrueStory" "E:\My Videos\Movies\Drama\True Story (2015).mp4" 3600
```

Here is the code for "RipWorkflow_DVD.bat"

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET input=%1
SET output=%2
SET minlength=%3
echo
echo %input%
echo %output%
echo

if not exist %input% ( mkdir "%input%" )
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\MakeMKV\makemkvcon64.exe" --minlength=%minlength% --decrypt mkv disc:0 0 "%input%
timeout /t 5 /nobreak

for %%F in (%input%\*.mkv) do (
echo %%~dpnxF
echo %output%

call "C:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandbrakeCLI.exe" -v1 -i %%~dpnxF --main-feature -o %output% -f mp4 --markers -e x264 -b 2000 -a 1 -E faac -6 dpl2 -R 44.1 -B 128 -D 1.75 --subtitle-forced -x ref=2:bframes=2:subme=6:mixed-refs=0:weightb=0:8x8dct=0:trellis=0

timeout /t 5 /nobreak
DEL %%F /Q
)
endlocal
```